# BigQuery - repeated field rows index

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-science

Is there a way to add index column of my aggregated array field in BigQuery? I'm using standard sql?

[image: query and results]

My goal is to have hits.hitNumber as a position in hits array ordered by hits.time

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use case for this?

Comment: When you later `UNNEST` an array, you can use e.g. `UNNEST(hits) WITH OFFSET off` to get the 0-based element index as a column named `off`, so you probably don't need the position in your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery SQL. As asked  - It takes original array (hits) and just simply "injects" number (hitNumber) ordered by one of field (time) while removing original hitNumber that lacks value or just incorrect and that's why you most likely needed to recalculate it. quite simple I think

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT sessionid, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY hit.time) hitNumber, hit.* except(hitNumber)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hit
  ) hits
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```